# Using radio buttons to select mp3 file to play

Tags: android

Im not necessarily asking for code but more the concept of how to achieve the following.

Im creating a bird-song app where I have a single-button that needs to play two different mp3 files as the user selects one or the other. My hope is to have the single 'play' button and then a radio button for selecting either mp3_A or mp3_B to play.

How would I go about achieving that?

THANKS!

Comment: what u have try for to archive this flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys. This topic describes a great fix!

http://blog.nelsondev.net/?p=385

Answer (score 0):

Please try to google keywords if you are really need something most likely someone has already have tutorials on it.

Here is something off the first type on google search: [site.](http://www.hrupin.com/2010/12/simple-android-mp3-media-player)

Oh completely forgot just use the basics for mediaplayer class like stop and open whenever a radiobutton is clicked that should solve this request of yours.

Comment: Thanks but this link does not answer the question at all. I see no reference to radio buttons or selecting different files by using a radio button in the code form the link. Am I missing something?